# how to configure in Artifactory remote nuget repo- https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Tags: nuget, artifactory

enter code here

I am trying to configure in Artifactory the "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" as remote nuget repository but I get "Connection failed: Error 400: Bad Request".

Any idea?

Comment: I tried to configre for URL-https://api.nuget.org, For Download Context Path- "v3/index.json" or "api/v2/package", for v3 Feed URL- "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" and for Feed Context Path":  "v3/index.json" or "api/v2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository URL should be configured with **https://www.nuget.org/** and Feed URL should be **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json** for NuGet packages.

Comment: Thanks, what should be the parameters of "Download Context Path" and "Feed Context Path" ?